MQ container , how admin user id is defined in the container
I am trying to understand, how the MQ admin user is configured in the IBM MQ container. The app id make sense that it's a system user and under the group MQclient. I am not getting any details on admin id part. How that is declared, and which group it belong to?

The repo for the developer image is here.
The instructions for building the advanced for developers image is here. Which shows that it is built by running the command -
make build-devserver

The makefile is here.
The makefile builds the image with the docker file found here.
The admin authentication / password is built in these lines in the docker file.
###############################################################################
# Build stage to build C code for custom authorization service (developer-only)
###############################################################################
# Use the Go toolset image, which already includes gcc and the MQ SDK
FROM builder as cbuilder
USER 0
# Install the Apache Portable Runtime code (used for simpleauth hash checking)
COPY authservice/ /opt/app-root/src/authservice/
WORKDIR /opt/app-root/src/authservice/mqsimpleauth
RUN make all

The image is built with the mqsc commands found here.
The admin relevant section is:
* Developer channels (Application + Admin)
DEFINE CHANNEL('DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN') CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) REPLACE
...

* Developer channel authentication rules
SET CHLAUTH('*') TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('*') USERSRC(NOACCESS) DESCR('Back-stop rule - Blocks everyone') ACTION(REPLACE)
...
SET CHLAUTH('DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody') DESCR('Allows admins on ADMIN channel') ACTION(REPLACE)
SET CHLAUTH('DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN') TYPE(USERMAP) CLNTUSER('admin') USERSRC(CHANNEL) DESCR('Allows admin user to connect via ADMIN channel') ACTION(REPLACE)
SET CHLAUTH('DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN') TYPE(USERMAP) CLNTUSER('admin') USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER ('mqm') DESCR ('Allow admin as MQ-admin') ACTION(REPLACE)



HI @chughts, The section you pinged above is the auth rules where admin and app is getting permission on the channel. I was asking, where is the admin user defined. I tried the exact same steps and tried to install MQ in linux and it's throwing error that unable to authenticate admin user.

I've updated my answer.

The admin user is created by the runmqdevserver program, you can see the details in the main.go of that component:
err = os.WriteFile("/run/mq.htpasswd", []byte(""), 0660)
if err != nil {
    logTermination(err)
    return err
}

if adminPwdset {
    err = htpasswd.SetPassword("admin", adminPassword, false)
    if err != nil {
        logTerminationf("Error setting admin password: %v", err)
        return err
    }
}

So you can see it's not a system user, and btw the app user is not a system user either, it's created the same way as the admin user.

In an IBM MQ container, the MQ admin user is not explicitly configured as a separate user. Instead, the container uses the mqm user, which is a system user that is part of the mqm group.
The mqm user is the default administrative user for IBM MQ, and it has full access to the queue manager and its resources. The mqm group is also the primary group for the mqm user.
Let me provide more details on the user configuration in an IBM MQ container.
The mqm user
The mqm user is a system user that is created during the installation of IBM MQ. This user is the default administrative user for IBM MQ, and it has full access to the queue manager and its resources.
In an IBM MQ container, the mqm user is used to run the container process. This means that the container process has full administrative access to the queue manager, allowing it to perform tasks such as:

Creating and managing queues, channels, and other resources
Configuring queue manager settings and properties
Managing user access and permissions
Managing user access and permissions

IN CONCLUSION .
The mqm user is part of the mqm group, which is the primary group for this user.
so there is no admin by default the admin is the user that use the mq contaniner under the group of mqm

Thanks @Mohammed for the info. I got your point. My question was wrt to, where is the admin user defined then and where it's added in the mqm group. When you login to the container, you will not find any admin user nor admin user under mqm group. But this user is able to login and perform admin activities at mq level. Where is it defined in the container ?

This is nonsense. The mqm user is NOT created in the standard container image. The queue manager runs under a random identity. Setting up admin/app userids is donee when creating the container.

HI @Mark, i was trying to follow the steps performed to create the container image for a  installation . The app user instruction was clear that it's a part of MQclient group and that was working in my installation. When i was trying to login as admin user(in MQ), it was throwing error. I was wondering, where admin user was created in the container. The previous answer explained that both app and admin are not actual user in the container.. Thanks again for your response.
